# What/when are the laravel storage/cache, storage/sessions, and storage/meta directories used for?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm setting up a master-replica setup in a load balanced cluster and am trying to figure out which directories to exclude from syncing to other machines. I naturally don't want to sync the storage/logs folder and DO want to sync the view cache folder (as "php artisan optimize" is run on the master), but I'm having a harder finding information on when the other directories in app/storage are used. Would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: You don't need to sync any files in `app/storage` as the Laravel will generate any files it needs inside that directory on it's own.

Comment: @Bogdan when I run "php artisan optimize" in production, it updates the view cache files, so they do need to be synced to the other servers.

Comment: If you need to sync them then do so. The idea is that anything in `app/storage` gets generated when needed (so if you wouldn't sync the compiled views they would be generated anyway when rendered on each server). But I do agree it's better to have them precompiled for better performance.

Comment: @Bogdan I'd normally agree with you, but I just ran into an issue today where a view was *not* regenerated as it was supposed to, resulting in a fatal error. The view files were synced over, but because the View files didn't sync, the app still used the cache for the view files instead. Not sure why that is, but it happened. Running the optimize command on that server fixed the issue.

Comment: That's strange. The view compiler checks the views if they are expired and recompiles them if necessary before rendering. So if the regular view synced was newer than the compiled view, it should of had been recompiled. Perhaps there was something wrong with the file timestamps. Does the sync process set the timestamps correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `storage/cache` and `storage/sessions` are used for, as their names suggest, cache and session storage. Specifically when using the `file` driver for those components. You probably don't want to include that.

`storage/meta` holds information the framework parses about itself, such as which components are provided by which service providers. You might want to include that, but I don't think it's crucial.